# Rally 2.0 SDK example doesn't load

Tags: extjs, rally

This is the generated App-uncompressed.html file from the example in Rally SDK website: When I copy and paste this code inside Rally as a custom HTMl app, it doesn't load anything. I just get a blank app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>newTeam</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc/sdk.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Rally.onReady(function () {
            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',

launch: function() {
    //Write app code here
 // The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
data : [
    {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
    {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
    {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
    //...
]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
store: states,
queryMode: 'local',
displayField: 'name',
valueField: 'abbr',
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
 }
});


        Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
            name:"newTeam",
            parentRepos:""
        });

    });
</script>


<style type="text/css">
    .app {
 /* Add app styles here */
}

</style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Also, I try to run the debug file in my browser and I get a `Rally not defined` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rally is not defined because it should be `rc1`, not `rc` , as your code shows.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc1/sdk.js"></script>
```

You may test these URLs in your browser:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/sdk-debug.js

https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/sdk.js

Comment: Also, my debug file doesn't work but it has the correct src .